# Jquery datatables - resetting issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, datatables

I have datatable to display the values from server when button click. It's kind of search functionality. if change the search text box value and click second time, it doesn't reflect the changes.

Second time datatable not displaying the correct values.

```
jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog ({ 
autoOpen: false,
height: 500,
width: 750,
modal: true,
buttons : {
"Search" : function() {
 jQuery.ajax({
 url : 'action="part"/>',
 data : {"product" : $("#productsTextArea").val()},
 dataType : 'json',
 success : function(data){
 var newarray=[];
 while(data.length > 0)  {
 newarray.push(data.splice(0,2));

 }

oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
        "aaData" : newarray,
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "bRetrieve" : true,
        "bPaginate" : true,
        "bSort" : true,
        "aaSorting" : [[ 4, "desc" ]],
        "iDisplayLength" : 15,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {"fnRender": function(o, val){

                    return o.aData[0];
                },
                "sClass":"prod", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
            {"fnRender": function(o, val){

                    return o.aData[1];
                },
                "sClass":"Description", "aTargets": [ 1 ] }
                ]
        });
```

Comment: Hard to know for sure from your description.  With Datatables you can either load the page with all of the table data, and then use the datatable search box to filter down those rows; or you can use an Ajax source which will poll your server after each character is typed in the search box.

Comment: Updated the code...This will helps to understand my question.

Comment: I don't see where you're re-initializing the datatable. You may be successfully getting back data via ajax, but you're not updating the table.

Comment: did you try to clear otable? like $('#products').empty(); ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-initialize DataTables on each ajax call:

```
success : function(data){
    oTable();
    var newarray=[];
    while(data.length > 0)  {
    newarray.push(data.splice(0,2));
}
```

Comment: Is there functions to referesh the datatable ? So before click the search, we can referesh the table.

Comment: Take a look at the API: http://www.datatables.net/api You may need to use fnDestroy() before you re-initialize.